# How do you make capacitors charge/discharge?

Tags: capacitor, discharge

Capacitors are used for storing energy, then discharging electricity. My question is, What is the process of making a charged capacitor discharge it's voltage? Hoping that my understanding isn't flawed, to charge it you connect it to a dc source. If I'm planning to make electronics though, that understanding probably won't be enough. I'm sorry if it's a really basic question but I've just started learning.

Comment: Capacitors store energy. There are lots of questions on this site that look at charging and discharging capacitors - a little bit of research should answer your question.

Comment: @JImDearden I've done research... That's why I posted the question

Comment: So in that research you must have come across a basic charging and discharging circuit such as http://www.schoolphysics.co.uk/age16-19/Electricity%20and%20magnetism/Electrostatics/text/Capacitor_charge_and_discharge/index.html. So what is it you don't understand?

Comment: What do you mean by 'process'? Its hard to tell what you are tying to ask, and wondering what you will understand as an explanation. Do you understand anything about current and voltage, or are you only looking at observable behaviour? At this level, understanding the theory to at least a basic approximation is essential, extraploating from observations will just trick you.

Comment: If you are wondering how to hook a capacitor to a battery and then get little lightning bolts out, or at least a good shock, capacitors don't work like that. You could look at camera flashes if you want some idea of how to make such a thing, but it involves a lot more parts than just a capacitor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say "discharge electricity", what do you think this stuff is being discharged? Energy is going in, and you are getting what out?

Capacitors do store energy, and they also *release energy*. There are many kinds of energy, so what kind is in a capacitor? It's electric potential energy, stored or released by the flow of electric charge, which a lot like water except it flows in wires.

A flow of charge is also called a current. When a current flows through the capacitor you get some charge going in one terminal and coming out the other. As this happens it gets harder and harder to move the charge, and more and more energy is stored in the capacitor.

To get the energy out of the capacitor you just stop trying to push a current through it. The "tension" that you've created in the capacitor by "stretching" it will push a current the other way so it returns to equilibrium, if there is someplace for the current to flow.

Answer (score 0):

Capacitor stores energy to its electric field (E), which occurs as a voltage between two points (or plates). This means that charge or some electrons are located on one of the plate and other plate is missing electrons.

Discharging this energy means that E field is discharged as electrons (current) flows out of plate to other plate.

Answer (score 0):

You charge caps with any voltage source , power supply or battery.

Although like some batteries they discharge themselves from internal high resistance. This can be quite a short time in seconds more or less a wide range depending on size, chemistry and quality.

Batteries are like really high density capacitors except the chemistry determines the dielectric-metal voltage potential built in.

So naturally like batteries, resistors discharge  either one.